# Login Page Redirect - Make HTML inaccessible if not logged in

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, active-directory

I have a basic login page in HTML where username and password fields are handled in javascript and the inputs are sent back to my Node API for a full AD authentication.

I have 4 more HTML sites which should only be accesible if the user has authenticated. The authentication part running in Node app works perfectly fine, however, I am not able to handle a session for the users who have logged in.
I also want to make all the 4 HTML sites inaccessible if the login fails or when the user logs out.

How do I handle the accessibility part by simply using HTML and Vanilla JS?

**login.js**

```
var express     = require('express');      
var app         = express();                
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var router      = express.Router();  
var cors        = require('cors');
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
const session = require('express-session');


app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.use(session({
    name: 'session.sid',
    secret: 'entersomepasswordhere',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 

app.use('/', router);

router.post('/api/Login1', function(req, res) 
{
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    console.log(username);


    var config = {
        url: 'abc',
        baseDN: 'dc=abc,dc=abc'
    };
    var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
    // Authenticate
    ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("Login Failed. Incorrect username or password");
            console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }
        if (auth) {
            console.log('Authenticated!');
            req.session.loggedin = true;
            res.redirect('/test.html');
        }
        else {
            console.log('Authentication failed!');
            res.send("Login Failed. Incorrect username or password");
        }
    });
});

router.get('/test.html', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.loggedin == true) //check if user is loggedin, replace with your variables/checks
        res.sendFile('/absolutepath/test.html');
    else
        res.redirect('/Login1');
})

app.use(cors());

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening at port ' + port);
```

Comment: So you basically want to check on the Front-End wheter a user is logged in or not and if not, redirect to another page?

Comment: Yes partially, the redirect is also being handled by Node App (it is redirecting to another html on successful login) except I also want to make the pages inaccessible if user is not logged in or login part fails.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your node app?

Comment: Included the code snippet

Comment: I guess you also have a router.post('/test.html') somewhere. Can you check inside of this route wheter a user is logged in or isn't?

Comment: Nowhere I am using router.post('/test.html') also not sure how do I check for user's existence. Upon login it just redirects to test.html. However I am using local storage in the front end. So the username and password gets stored in browser's file system (if this helps)

Comment: Can you show the file structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is. The core module just handles every request for you, therefore every http request first looks in the core middleware if it finds a matching html file. You need to place

```
app.use(cors());
```

After you've defined your routes and define a custom route to your test.html. See the following example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 

//use routes on the localhost:8080 path
app.use('/', router);

//Relevant part:
router.get('/test.html', function(req, res) {
    var loggedin = true; //false if not loggedin
    if (loggedin)
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
    else
        res.redirect('https://www.google.com/');
})

//This needs to be after the routes
app.use(cors());

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening at port ' + port);
```

You can set loggedin to false to see what happens if a user isn't loggedin and true if a user is loggedin.

**UPDATE**

In order to save if a user is loggedin, i recommend using the express-session module: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html

You can include it like the following:

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    name: 'session.sid',
    secret: 'entersomepasswordhere',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

After authenticating you can just set

```
req.session.loggedin = true;
```

and then just check if

```
req.session.loggedin == true
```

Note: you can replace loggedin with any variable name you like, and you can also set multiple session cookies.

In your case just set req.session.loggedin = true before you redirect to your test.html and then perform the check in there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213243/discussion-on-answer-by-philip-f-login-page-redirect-make-html-inaccessible-i).